# How to achieve this sort of navigation?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am a bit new to android development, and I do not know how to achieve something like this? I thought it is bottom navigation view and fragments connected to it, but maybe there is a proper or correct way to achieve something like this ?

So when you click on tools, it expands from the bottom to top and gives you more buttons. [image: From this screen][image: To this].

What is the best way of achieving this or maybe there are some links I can read on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to me. You can read more about them in item 4 here: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031